# Starting web server with `php -S` not reading php.ini file

Tags: php

I have a local project I am working on. I have at the root of my project and `index.php` `php.ini` and `local_connector.php`.

When I run `php -S ...` from inside my project. It says that the php.ini is not loaded.

This is the code I have in my `index.php`

```
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();
if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
```

This is what I have in my `php.ini`

```
auto_prepend_file = "./local_connector.php"
```

The idea is I will have multiple pages that use the `local_connector` but I don't want to include it in every file. Is this possible with `php`'s local server?

I would rather not set up an entire local apache server, so if someone knows a good way of getting this to work, or a work around. That would be very helpful.

Comment: Use the `-c` flag to specify the path to the `php.ini` you want to load. Eg `php -c php.ini -S ...`.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much!